# How to output my files to the host machine on docker

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

Im new, very new to this whole docker thing and also programming thing.

I built a simple script that outputs a series of files (namely a .tsv and a .txt) from an api.

Now, this works fine running the script on the regular linux terminal (I know, thats not the same thing).

However, with docker, it never seems to output my file to my host machine.

Interesting thing is, when running 'ls' in the docker terminal, all the files show up!

```
sudo docker run -it -v /home/USER/DESKTOP/PROJECT:/CONTAINERWORKINGDIR IMAGENAME
```

also, tried mounting it via the dockerfile, which also seems to not do anything.

I don't get an error, the host path is just empty, always...

running 'ls' will show my files, sitting neatly in the docker directory, but when verifying on the host path, its empty. Also, verified that all the files are accessible.

Docker File:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a base image
FROM python:3.11.1-alpine

# Set the working directory to /AudiblePy
WORKDIR /AudiblePy

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /AudiblePy
COPY main.py /AudiblePy
COPY additional.py /AudiblePy
COPY requirements.txt /AudiblePy

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Would love some help, Im stumped and it seems that I can't find any information on why this is...

Comment: can you please paste your `docker run` command?

Comment: sudo docker run -it -v /home/kevin/Desktop/Docker_Projects:/AudiblePy IMAGENAME

Comment: seems totally fine to me. can you show the output of `ls` command from within the container and from the host?

Comment: From Docker Terminal: 'ls -l'
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Dec 23 03:47 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           526 Dec 23 02:43 additional.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         25966 Dec 23 03:48 library.tsv
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          4265 Dec 23 03:46 main.py
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root            33 Dec 23 02:50 requirements.txt
/AudiblePy # ls

Comment: host is empty 'ls' returns nothing. * in specified directory